# in STL, how to swap 2 dimension vector

Tags: c++, stl

In header file, I declared the following as a public member variable:

```
vector< vector<unsigned char> > arImage;
```

In source code, I define temp

```
vector<vector<unsigned char> > temp (numImage, vector<unsigned char>(sizeImage));
```

Now I try to ,

```
temp.swap(arImage);
```

But an error occured. (detail errors are omitted because they are not English)

```
    with
    [
        _Ty=std::vector<unsigned char>
    ]
```

////////////
Addition,,,,,,,,

I want to swap

```
    vector<vector<unsigned char> > to vector<vector<unsigned char> >
```

I'm working with MFC. I can't find proper method, so I actually take another approach.

In header file,

```
    vector< vector<unsigned char> > * arImage;
```

In source code,

```
    arImage = new vector< vector<unsigned char> > (numImage, vector<unsigned char>(sizeImage));
```

But this approach is not comfortable.(this approach is no error)

I want to use arImage[i][j].

In this approach, I have to use (*arImage)[i][j]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the _full_ and _unedited_ error message.

Comment: It's not surprising that you can't swap `vector<vector<unsigned char>>` with `vector<unsigned char>`. What's your question?

Comment: You're trying to swap the contents of two variables, one of which is a vector of characters ("1D") and the other is a vector of vectors of characters ("2D"). This makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm very sorry. I modify 2nd line. Original source is what you see now.

Comment: @user1844810 That looks perfectly OK now. Please show the real code an error message. The partial error message hints that the type of `arImage` isn't quite right.

Comment: *"(detail errors are omitted)"* - In fact you omitted everything else of the error message *except* for the insignificant detail that it is about some template instantiated with `std::vector<unsigned char>`, which isn't that hard to guess.

Comment: The reason why I omit details is that the error message is written by not English..

Comment: That error is solved,,, I think that there is another problem. I want to upload full source codes, but this program is made by MFC..

Comment: Thanks to all......Original error is solved, There is another error, but I try to do myself..

Comment: Solved!!! In visual studio, I tried to Rebuild, then complete... Thank s....!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are doing wrong here is you are trying to swap `vector< unsigned char >` with vector of `vector< unsigned char >` which is not possible.

`Vector arImage` has items of type `unsigned char` while temp type is `vector<vector<unsigned char> >` so temp items are `vector<unsigned char>`.

So it make sense as can not swap `vector<unsigned char>` with `unsigned char`. Similarly you can not swap `vector< unsigned char >` with `vector <vector< unsigned char >>`.

I hope it explains everything.

Comment: Thank you very much, by the way what I do? If I modify first line vector< vector<unsigned char> > arImage;  Also an error occured

Comment: @user1844810 would be better if you explain what you are trying to achieve here. Either you need to change vector<vector<unsigned char> > temp to vector<unsigned char> temp or decide where you want to actually use it.

Comment: I want to swap vector<vector<unsigned char> > to vector<vector<unsigned char> >

Comment: If its not working this way.... try to iterate through it and swap each elements... of arImage and temp

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose index which have to be swaped in your `temp`:

```
int index = 0;
temp[index].swap(arImage);
```

You declared temp as vector of vectors (2D). So swapping will perform with the same type of variable (which is logical). But you try to swap with 1D vector what is wrong, that's what compiler says to you.

Comment: Thank you,,, If I want to swap "temp" and "arImage", what should I do?

Comment: You must do as i wrote or change type of arImage. But you must provide full error message